# Is there any performance difference between ASC and DESC when ORDER BY clause is properly indexed?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say the tableA has a clustered index on Column1

Is there any performance impact differences between the following statements:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Column1 FROM tableA  ORDER BY Column1 ASC

SELECT TOP 5 Column1 FROM tableA  ORDER BY Column1 DESC
```

**Update, and the catch**

@TheGameiswar answer is correct. However, there is a big catch where there are multiple columns in the order by clause:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Column1 FROM tableA  ORDER BY Column1 , Column2 DESC
```

actually means

```
SELECT TOP 5 Column1 FROM tableA  ORDER BY Column1 ASC, Column2 DESC
```

Above statement imposes a Sort query processor operator to the plan and makes the query very inefficient.

So, make sure the descending sort order includes "DESC" for both columns

```
SELECT TOP 5 Column1 FROM tableA  ORDER BY Column1 DESC , Column2 DESC
```

Comment: Theoretically, you might be able to detect a very, very, small difference, based on one direction having slightly better loop support than the other in the CPU hardware. However DB query performance is typically dominated by disk access, which would overwhelm any CPU performance differences by multiple orders of magnitude in almost all scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference or performance penalty..

SQL server will use an index if available(for the query you used ) to do scan backwards or forwards depending on sorting..

I have a numbers table which has index on number column like below.Below is the definition of index..

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [n] ON [dbo].[Numbers]
(
    [Number] ASC
)
```

As you can see above index is by created with ASC option(which is default)..now lets see how database engine deals with below query

```
select top 10* from numbers
order by number desc
```

[image]

You can see SQL decided to scan the index backwards..